# Function Domain output

Tags: functions

I am completely new in Mathematica, and I believe the answer to my question should be very simple.
When I try to find the domain of a function, the output is not what I expected. For example, when I plug in FunctionDomain[x^2,x], the ouput comes out as "True" (when I expect to say all real numbers), and when I plug in FunctionDomain[1/(Sin[x]),x], the output comes out as x/$\pi$$\not\in \mathbb{Z}$ (even though I know this is true, I am wondering if there is a way to have it say all x such that x is not multiple of $\pi$. For the first function, is this like some standard answer given from Mathematica whenever the domain are all real numbers?
For the second function, is this the only output I can obtain from Mathematica (I find the other one to be more intuitive)?

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `True` means that every real number is in the domain of the stated function.  You will find this answer more "intuitive" as you work in *Mathematica* because this output can be called by other (Boolean) functions.

And yes, it is standard output of the form:  ${x \over \pi} \notin \mathbb{Z}$, and as far as I'm concerned, perfectly reasonable, and "intuitive."

(By the way, you have extraneous parentheses in your first example.)

Comment: Thank you David for your response. Much appreciated.